# Tiny mce unable to load in ci

Tags: codeigniter

gsaconst2/application/site/views/index.php

I already place tiny mce js in assets but unable to load it correctly.  Can anyone help me check my codes if it is correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="<?php site_url('assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script> 


</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<script src="<?php site_url('assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything with this:  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

Comment: @David Javascript part is looking good. Are you sure that your JavaScript import URL is correct?

Comment: I already get some part done,  this is the continuation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311906/tinymce-with-codeigniter